# why left value dosen't work in position sticky

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a sticky sidebar but `left` property is not working and my sidebar doesn't move to the right side of my sidebar container although `top` property is working correctly.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 3000px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 380px;
  border-left: #6445ff solid 5px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 10px;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #00003610;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="page-top">
    <p class="head-text">learn more about your favorite cities</p>
    <p class="navigation"></p>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <div class="sidebar-container">
      <div class="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="article1">
          <p class="article-title">introducing paris</p>
          <img src="paris1.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
          <span class="article-subtitle"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-effect"></div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="article2">
          <p class="article-title">introducing berlin</p>
          <img src="berlin1.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
          <span class="article-subtitle"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-effect"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

I don't want to use `transform` or `margin` to solve this issue, unless that it's not possible or valid.

Comment: you use `position:absolute` and `right:10px`on sticky box's parent `.sidebar-container`

Comment: Do you have to have the "sidebar" div inside the "sidebar-container" div? When it's removed the positioning works fine.